# Python set locale

Tags: python, datetime, calendar, setlocale

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import calendar
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'srb_srb')  
def main():
    days = list(calendar.day_name)
    day = input("Input day:")
    if day in days:
        print(day)
        print (days)
    else:
        print("Error")
main()
```

*(this is just experimental code)*

First I just tryed to print list of days on Serbian. But, when I run the code it print this:

```
['?????????', '??????','?????','????????','?????','??????','??????']
```

It's probably because local is on Serbian cyrilic so it's should probably looks like this:

```
['понедељак','уторак','среда','четвртак','петак','субота','недеља']
```

But I have to check is inputed day is the same as in text file where days are writen on serbian latin, so is there any way to convert cyrilic to latin?

If I input, for example, понедељак in cmd on Serbian cyrilic just to check does my experimental code work it prints

```
?????????
['?????????', '??????','?????','????????','?????','??????','??????']

*понедељак len = 9
????????? len = 9*
```

I need some universal solution, because user probably would not run this code on my computer. :D

Comment: `Python2` or 3? 2 is more easy

Comment: @RaminNietzsche 
Python 3.4.2